# menu with arrow down when hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

after some helps here, i have another issue in my navbar
i have a navbar with a submenu items, and the style of this navbar have a arrow down when hover, but when the mouse leave the menu, the background lost your hover effect, need keep it hovered when mouse move to submenu, i search another issues like this, but none question have a menu like this with arrow down.

see image below:

[image: see image below, my menu have a arrow down at end of link]

how i can do it?

i tried do it with jquery to show menu when hover but not work, the menu link lost the hover effect

Comment: You will need to use the pseudo-elements `:before`/`:after` to create a triangle on `:hover`. I wrote a post on triangles in CSS which give some good examples that may be helpful. Otherwise there are a lot of resources for dealing with CSS triangles. http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2013/03/triangles-in-css.html

Comment: here are: http://jsfiddle.net/6xKL9/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a menu with an structure like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item4</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Subitem</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</u>
```

You need to put the `:hover` effect in the `li` ---> `li:hover` not in the `a` tag to keep the effect while the mouse is on the submenu.

View this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/Wrnex/13/**

Comment: is possible use class in differents li's to put a custom background inside them, like my screenshot above?

Comment: like in the submenu's li? it's possible

Comment: its because each menu have a different background size.

Comment: Yes you can apply a unique class to each li ..

Comment: i have the normalize.css and it throw box-sizing: border-box; in all elements, and it broken the menu. but i can solve it.